# How do I generate an F# Azure Function stub at build time?

Tags: f#, azure-functions, code-generation

Let's say I have a beautiful F# function like this:

```fsharp
let doWork (item: string) = 
    printf "Hello %s" item
```

and now I want to create an Azure Function from it. All I need to do is to declare another similar function but decorate it with a specific attribute, for instance:

```fsharp
[<FunctionName("DoWork")>]
let DoWork([<QueueTrigger("myqueue")>] item: string) = doWork item
```

After doing this for the 20th time I'm asking myself whether I could generate those functions with attributes at build time. Something like

```
let functionApp = generateFunctionsMagic [doWork; doWork2; doWork3]
```

would expand to 3 annotated methods. I'm fine with other ways to annotate what to generate.

What could be a valid approach to do so?

Comment: I've added example for AST rewriting to my answer below

Answer (score 1):

There are no easy ways for codegen in F#

You could make you own codegen based on [Fantomas](https://github.com/fsprojects/fantomas).

Usual workflow:

1. Read *.fs file
2. Invoke FSharp.Compiler.Service to get AST from text
3. Analyze AST
4. Rewrite AST (in case of Fantomas, adding `LongIdent` nodes for example)
5. Convert AST to text
6. Write text to *.fs file

You could fork Fantomas for your own codegen tool.

P.S. Also, this could help - [Ionide Analyzers](https://medium.com/lambda-factory/introducing-f-analyzers-772487889429). But afaik they don't support AST rewriting. AST only for analyzing the problem and after that you have to work with text directly.

## Added

I've created [example](https://gist.github.com/Szer/1759baf6925710e9e7c9d9ae51e4dc05) of codegen based on AST